# Book where a brain/object controls humans so that everyone walks and moves in the same rhythm and pattern

Tags: story-identification, books

It's an old book about this thing controlling humans and making them do everything in the same set of patterns and actions, until someone tries to break free and destroy it.

Comment: Brain controls everyone to walk in the same rhythm? Must be http://xkcd.com/389/ "Keeping Time".

Comment: probable duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/126937/unknown-science-fiction-space-book (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Comment: @Otis the answers are the same (well, assuming they're correct), but the _questions_ are entirely different, so don't think it counts as a duplicate.

Comment: @JohnC, the general operating principle for scifi story ID questions is that "same answer" counts as "duplicate." This wouldn't be closeable until the OP confirmed via comment or acceptance, anyway. I just put the link in anyway to help make it easier for anyone coming to this page to find the other answer.

Answer (score 11):

Possibly [A Wrinkle in Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Wrinkle_in_Time), by [Madeleine L'Engle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madeleine_L%27Engle). The characters travel (via *tesseract*) through several dimensions, one of which is controlled by **IT** - a shadowy, disembodied brain that makes everyone behave identically. For instance, children bouncing balls on the sidewalk in rhythm. When one child makes a mistake, he's taken off and punished.

**IT** doesn't get destroyed in the book, though. Instead, the main character, Meg, rescues her brother, Charles Wallace, from **IT's** influence and they escape the planet.

Answer (score 3):

"We" by Yevgeny Zamyatin has people walking, even eating in sync. It was written in Russian amd published in 1921. There's no over seeing brain or computer, but absolute conformity is driven by ideology instead. Could this be your book?